# Trying to replace all evaluate functions with dynamic notation in ColdFusion 9

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Hello I have been tasked with replacing all evaluate() functions in this coldfusion app. I am having some issues with some fairly complex evaluations and I just can't figure it ou.

When it is a simple change like
This:

```
<cfif isNumeric(evaluate("form.value_#REPORT_FIELD_ID#"))>
```

To This:

```
<cfif isNumeric(form["value_" & REPORT_FIELD_ID])>
```

It's all good but for this:

```
<cfif evaluate("qrySearch.#qryReportFields.FIELD_NAME[qryReportFields.currentRow]#") eq true>
```

Not so much

I have tried several things. I thought this would work

```
<cfif qrySearch[#qryReportFields.FIELD_NAME[qryReportFields.currentRow]#] eq true>
```

But it throws a  Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values. error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try using the variables scope as the top level structure.  Also, put current row into it's own set of square brackets.

Comment: What type of variable is qrySearch?

Comment: it is in the variables scope.

I tried both with no luck :( now I am getting this error. 
 Element ACTIVE is undefined in a Java object of type class coldfusion.runtime.VariableScope.

ACTIVE is the column I'm looking for though.

Answer (score 2):

I believe if you use bracket notation for query column name you have to also include row number.

```
<cfif qrySearch[qryReportFields.FIELD_NAME[qryReportFields.currentRow]][qrySearch.currentrow] eq true>
```

Or just pass 1 instead of currentrow if only one record, not in loop, etc

Comment: I get this error with that Element CURRENTROW is undefined in QUERYSEARCH.

Comment: I had a typo... qrySearch

Comment: This worked
<cfif qrySearch[qryReportFields.FIELD_NAME[qryReportFields.currentRow]][qrySearch.currentrow] eq true>

Thank you for the help :)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: @StevenPennington - While you are rewriting the code, may as well get rid of the redundant `eq true`. Any expression that returns true or yes can be written simply as `<cfif someCondition>` instead of `<cfif someCondition eq true>`. Also, if it were me, I would split it into separate lines - if only to increase readability.

Comment: +1 for Leigh. I was just about to type the same comment until I saw there was one more. When I refreshed, you beat me to it by a few seconds. Once again, you seem to be in my head. Scary place to be, ya know.

Comment: @Shawn - Yours or mine? (If it is anything like mine ... both ;-)

Comment: @Leigh Probably both. All I know is that as many times as I've started to answer a question here only to be beat by you, I owe you a brew at the next CF conference I run into you.